# How to load point data into zend_db_row classes?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, point, zend-db-table

I have following classes

- `My_Table extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`
- `My_Row extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract`

I my table has a column of the type `Point`

```
var_dump($row->point);
string(25) "=
ףp@@=
ףp�^@"
```

How can I fetch the  `point` column as text ("32.23,122.21") through these classes? The select should probably have

```
CONCAT( X( `point` ) , ',', Y( `point` ) ) AS point
```

But I don't know what methods or properties to override. I've already tried manually setting $_cols in `My_Table` to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

When creating an instance of Zend_Db_Table, you can specify to include custom columns..

```
$table_with_point = new Table_With_Point(array('point_coords' => "CONCAT( X( `point` ) , ',', Y( `point` ) )"));
```